# \crefrange doesn't work for "assumption" environments using amsmath

Tags: cross-referencing, amsmath, cleveref

I am using `\cleveref` package for which the `\crefrange` feature is not working for `assumption` environments. Can anybody tell me how I may fix this?

Here's the code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath,latexsym,amsthm,amsfonts,mathtools}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{colorlinks, breaklinks, citecolor=cyan, linkcolor=cyan, urlcolor=cyan}
\usepackage[nameinlink,noabbrev,sort&compress]{cleveref}

\theoremstyle{plain}% Theorem-like structures provided by amsthm.sty
    \newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
    \newtheorem{lemma}{Lemma}
    \newtheorem{corollary}{Corollary}
    \newtheorem{proposition}{Proposition}
    \newtheorem{assumption}{Assumption}

    \theoremstyle{remark}
    \newtheorem{remark}{Remark}
    \newtheorem{notation}{Notation}

    \theoremstyle{definition}
    \newtheorem{definition}{Definition}
    \newtheorem{example}{Example}
    \newtheorem{problem}{Problem}

\begin{document}

\begin{theorem}\label{thm:T1}
Some theorem
\end{theorem}

\begin{theorem}\label{thm:T2}
Some other theorem
\end{theorem}

\crefrange{thm:T1}{thm:T2}

\begin{assumption}\label{asm:A1}
First Assumption
\end{assumption}

\cref{asm:A1}      


\begin{assumption}\label{asm:A2}
Second Assumption
\end{assumption}
\Cref{asm:A2}

\crefrange{asm:A1}{asm:A2}

\end{document}
```

Here's the output:
[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The issue you raise is not related to `\crefrange` *per se*, nor is it related to the `amsmath` package. Instead, it arises because the `cleveref` package has not been informed, by default, how to create the *plural form* of the noun "assumption". Hence, macros such as `\crefrange`, which are programmed to use the plural forms of nouns, cannot perform their work correctly.

Consider the following, simplified version of your code. [Aside: Note that it's not necessary to load `amsmath` explicitly if `mathtools` is loaded; likewise, it's not necessary to load `amsfonts` explicitly if `amssymb` is loaded. Separately, there can be no valid reason for loading the ancient `latexsym` package if `amssymb` is loaded.] Observe that both `\cref{asm:A1,asm:A2}` and `\crefrange{asm:A1}{asm:A2}` fail to generate correct cross-referencing call-outs.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsthm,mathtools}
\usepackage[colorlinks,allcolors=cyan]{hyperref}
\usepackage[nameinlink,noabbrev]{cleveref}

\newtheorem{assumption}{Assumption}

%% Uncomment to get correct cross-referencing call-outs:
%\crefname{assumption}{assumption}{assumptions}

\begin{document}
\begin{assumption}\label{asm:A1}First\end{assumption}
\begin{assumption}\label{asm:A2}Second\end{assumption}

\Cref{asm:A1,asm:A2}      

\Crefrange{asm:A1}{asm:A2}
\end{document}
```

---

What to do? Just add the instruction

```
\crefname{assumption}{assumption}{assumptions}
```

in the preamble (after loading `cleveref`, naturally) and all will be well.

[image]

---

*Addendum*: You may well have two follow-up questions. First, which counter labels are recognized by `cleveref` by default, in both singular and plural form? Second, how does `cleveref` manage to generate singular-form cross-references to  `assumption` environments correctly -- note that `\cref{asm:A1}` outputs `assumption 1` rather than just `?? 1` -- even though it doesn't handle plural-form instances correctly without help from a suitable `\crefname` instruction?

Regarding the first question: As of September 2019, the file `cleveref.sty` provides the following 20 directives if the package option `capitalize` is *not* set and if the language option `english` (which is the default) is in force:

```
  \crefname@preamble{page}{page}{pages}%
  \crefname@preamble{table}{table}{tables}%
  \crefname@preamble{part}{part}{parts}%
  \crefname@preamble{chapter}{chapter}{chapters}%
  \crefname@preamble{section}{section}{sections}%
  \crefname@preamble{appendix}{appendix}{appendices}%
  \crefname@preamble{enumi}{item}{items}%
  \crefname@preamble{footnote}{footnote}{footnotes}%
  \crefname@preamble{theorem}{theorem}{theorems}%
  \crefname@preamble{lemma}{lemma}{lemmas}%
  \crefname@preamble{corollary}{corollary}{corollaries}%
  \crefname@preamble{proposition}{proposition}{propositions}%
  \crefname@preamble{definition}{definition}{definitions}%
  \crefname@preamble{result}{result}{results}%
  \crefname@preamble{example}{example}{examples}%
  \crefname@preamble{remark}{remark}{remarks}%
  \crefname@preamble{note}{note}{notes}%
  \crefname@preamble{algorithm}{algorithm}{algorithms}%
  \crefname@preamble{listing}{listing}{listings}%
  \crefname@preamble{line}{line}{lines}%
```

(A very similar set of directives operates if the package option `capitalize` is set. The default language option is `english`. If a suitable alternative language-related option is in force, non-English forms of the name labels will be created. As of September 2019, the available language options are, sorted alphabetically, `brazilian`, `catalan`, `danish`, `dutch`, `esperanto`[!], `french`, `german` and `ngerman`, `italian`, `norsk`, `russian`, `spanish`, `swedish`, and `ukrainian`.) Observe that singular-form and plural-form labels are predefined for the following 9 theorem-like environments: `theorem`, `lemma`, `corollary`, `proposition`, `definition`, `result`, `example`, `remark`, and `note`. Conversely, observe that `assumption` is *not* among these 9 environments. That's why it's necessary to provide the instruction `\crefname{assumption}{assumption}{assumptions}` in the preamble of your document. While you're at it, you may want to run suitable `\crefname` instructions for the `notation` and `problem` environments as well if you have the need to create plural-form cross-references to these environments.

On to the second question: How come that `\cref{asm:A1}` "works" even though, as we just confirmed, no name labels are defined by `cleveref` for an environment called `assumption`? Well, as long as the theorem-like environments (such as `assumption`) are defined via `\newtheorem` statements *after* both `amsthm` and `cleveref` are loaded -- an ordering strongly encouraged by `cleveref`, by the way -- `cleveref` is clever enough [pun intended] to parse the instruction

```
\newtheorem{assumption}{Assumption}
```

and treat the word "Assumption" as the singular-form label associated with the environment called `assumption`. Pretty nifty, in my opinion!

Comment: Thanks Mico for such insights :)